# Getting number of differences between 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, comparison

I want to compare two dataframes (same number of rows and columns in both) using python and to get number of differences, what would be the best way for this?

```
def numberOfDifferencess(df1, df2):
    if df1.equals(df2):
        numberOfDifferences = 0
    else:
        ?????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df
    a    b
0   1  999
1   2    3
2   3  345
3  56    8
4   7   54
df_b
    a    b
0   1  111
1   2    3
2   3  345
3  56    8
4   7   54
```

Comparing:

```
df.count().sum() - (df == df_b).astype(int).sum().sum()
1 #this is the number of differences
```

In a function:

```
def numberOfDifferencess(df1, df2):
    return df1.count().sum() - (df1 == df2).astype(int).sum().sum()
```

Essentially `(df == df_b).astype(int).sum().sum()` will sum up the overlap (field in one equals field in another) between the two dataframes.

**Quick Speed Test**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (1000,1000)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (1000,1000)))

%timeit numberOfDifferencess(df1, df2)
%timeit number_of_diff(df1, df2) # using spies006 function for comparison (see below)

10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 428 ms per loop
```

Not surprisingly, this approach is ideal. Iterating over a dataframe is generally not the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df1
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  4


>>> df2
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  8  4
```

Here is one way to do it, I've just built off of what you already have. I use `loc` to iterate of the each of the rows in `df1` and `df2`.

```
>>> numberOfDifferences = 0
>>> for i in range(len(df1)):
...     if not df1.loc[i, :].equals(df2.loc[i, :]): 
...             numberOfDifferences+=1
... 
>>> numberOfDifferences
1
```

If you'd like it as a function as implied, it follows.

```
def number_of_diff(df1, df2):
    differences = 0
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        if not df1.loc[i, :].equals(df2.loc[i, :]):
            differences += 1
    return differences
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the underlying ndarrays functionality for this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(data=[
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [6, 7, 8, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 2]])

dfd = DataFrame(data=[
    [1, 2, 1, 4],
    [6, 9, 8, 4],
    [1, 1, 3, 2]])

diff = df.values != dfd.values

result = diff.flatten().sum()
```